# I did the "Expose an API" in Azure but cannot get the token for that scope to a client program

Tags: azure, webapi, scopes, azure-authentication

I'm trying to build a WebAPI and want to use a scope to limit permissions for other clients applications.  I created a scope "BuildingAccess" on the Expose an API blade, and added the other client application to the authorized list with that scope.  However when I use a client program to try and get the token with that scope I get the "`AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.`" error

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("removed")
            .WithTenantId("removed")
            .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
        scopes.Add(".default");
        scopes.Add("https://localhost:44371/BuildingAccess");

        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Token acquired \n");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex)
        when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
        {
            // Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form "https://resourceurl/.default"
            // Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Scope provided is not supported");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
```

The only format that seems to work is when the scope is set to https://localhost:44371/.default.  All the other combinations below where I add the BuildingAccess scope fail with the error below for the different formats I've tried.

- The scope `api://333333-2222-1111-0000-aaaaaaaaaaaaa/BuildingAccess https://localhost:44371/.default` is not valid.
- The scope `api://333333-2222-1111-0000-aaaaaaaaaaaaa/.default api://333333-2222-1111-0000-aaaaaaaaaaaaa/BuildingAccess` is not valid.
- The scope `.default BuildingAccess` is not valid.
- The scope `BuildingAccess` is not valid.
- The scope `api://333333-2222-1111-0000-aaaaaaaaaaaaa/BuildingAccess`
- The scope `https://localhost:44371/BuildingAccess` is not valid.

If the one that works the `https://localhost:44371/.default`, then my server side has an error because it failed with

> Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException'
>   in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll

and I get an Unauthorized response on the client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is I need to have Admin Consent for app to app permissions to work.  This is a restricted action on the Azure tenant I'm on so I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

1.You should enter the correct format range, make sure to use the following format：api://{Your-Application-ID}/your_scope_name.

2.Then you should grant permissions to the API and select the administrator to agree.
[image]

Comment: Well for point 1. I've tried all the combinations without success, which was the bottom of my post.  For 2. I wonder if my issue is I cannot Grant admin consent for my organization.  That seems to be a restricted privilege.  I thought I got around it by adding the client application as a "Authorized client applications" in my appregistration and giving them the BuildingAccess scope when doing that.

Comment: Okay I confirmed the issue with another developer.  The issue is that Admin Consent is a restricted permission and I need that in order for this to work.