# An error occurred while requesting the token with "Expose an API” scope. AADSTS70011:The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Tags: azure, authentication, scope, azure-active-directory

I have added [scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws1ae.png) to *"Expose an API"* on the *Azure portal* with the reference of Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposing-delegated-permissions-scopes) and granted [API permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7EtH.png) to that scope. After that I request a token using [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0H7J.png) it returns an error `AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.`

When I try scope like this `{resource}/.default` works fine. But, I need scope like  `{resource}/access_as_user`

I have already tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375072/i-did-the-expose-an-api-in-azure-but-cannot-get-the-token-for-that-scope-to-a), but it did not work.

[image: postman]

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Check out my updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the wrong authentication flow, and you have granted `delegated permissions`. In this case, you should use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Then you can set the scope to: `api://{resource}/access_as_user`.

**Add：**

This is my test process:

1. First obtain the authorization code in the browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=5f11e827-xxxx-4f1f-aa05-33a33f806aab
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms/index
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://c848e37d-xxxx-4cd8-b9bf-0b2aa6927a82/access_as_user
&state=12345
```

2. Use the authorization code to redeem the access token:

[image]

Comment: I am doing with Auth code flow, but I am getting same error.